# Finding $E[X^2Y^3]$ if $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=2(1-|\,x\,|\,)y$ for $-1<x<1$, $0<y<1$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am new here but I just wanted to check and see if I'm doing this right.

The joint density function of two random variables X and Y is given as follows:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=2(1-|\,x\,|\,)y,\quad{}-1<x<1,\quad{}0<y<1$

Calculate $E[X^2Y^3]$.

What I thought I could do is split the integrals up

$$\int_{-1}^0\int_0^1x^2y^3*2(1+x)ydydx+\int_0^1\int_0^1x^2y^3*2(1-x)ydydx$$

But this is really awful looking, so I am unsure if I am actually doing this right.

Comment: Is it really that bad? Just carefully integrate. The terms are polynomials, and relatively easy to integrate. If it makes your life easier, the distribution implies $x,y$ are independent, defining $f_Y(y)=y$ and $f_X(x)=2(1-|x|)$, so that $E[X^2Y^3]=E[X^2]E[Y^3]$.

Comment: @AlexR. It isn't awful, but it didn't really seem right when I was doing it. I did get $1\over15$ though which I believe is the right answer.

Comment: You can do the calculations directly. It is a pain in the butt, but it is tedious, rather than difficult, and makes good practice.

Comment: The factor 2 goes with $f_Y$: $f_Y(y) = 2y$, $0<y<1$, and  $f_X(x)=1-|x|$, $|x|<1$.

Comment: If you are in for simple computations, note that $(X,Y)$ is independent, that $|X|$ has PDF $2(1-x)$ on $(0,1)$, and that $Y$ has PDF $2y$ on $(0,1)$, hence $$E(X^2)=\int_0^12(1-x)x^2dx=2\left(\frac13-\frac14\right)=\frac16$$ while $$E(Y^3)=\int_0^12y\,y^3dy=2\frac15$$ hence $$E(X^2Y^3)=\frac16\frac25=\frac1{15}$$